# Enumerating combinations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, discrete-mathematics

It's easy to enumerate all combinations of **n** things taken **k** at a time with [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html) function.

How to build a one-to-one correspondence of a combination and its index (from *1* to *n!/(k!(n-k)!)*)?

Of course, it's possible using [NCHOOSEK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nchoosek.html), but it's not practical if **n** is rather large (more than 15 as pointed in documentation).

How to implement **COMBINATION_TO_INDEX** and **INDEX_TO_COMBINATION** functions right?

**UPD:**
Found implementation of an index to combination function: [ONECOMB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23064-onecomb).
Still looking for reverse function (combination to index).

Comment: Permutations or combinations?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, and I rarely do understand questions on SO correctly, you want to devise a function which outperforms the built-in NCHOOSEK, in particular for cases where n > 15.  I won't go so far as to say that it's impossible to write Matlab functions which outperform the intrinsic Matlab functions, but possibly very difficult.

Comment: Thanks Oli, updated the question. I'm talking about combinations.

Comment: Mark, i'm not talking about implementing another nchoosek function. The task is to make a pair of functions that establish a one-to-one correspondence between a combination and its index.

Comment: Linking related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662100

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about *permutations*, as your title suggest, the [perms function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/perms.html) produces all possible permutations of a vector.

If you want *combinations*, you can certainly brute force it using the perms function a-like so:

```
x=zeros(n,1);
x(1:k)=1;

y=unique(perms(x),'rows');
combs=y*yourvector;
```

This is rather inefficient, as it computes all the permutations, which will usually be orders of magnitude greater than the number of combinations.